# Can transitive replacement prove axiom of replacement?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, axioms

**Transitive Replacement:** $\forall x \in a \, \exists!  y \ \varphi(x,y), \implies \\\exists b: Trans(b) \land a \in b \land \forall x \in a \exists! y \in b \ \varphi^b(x,y) $

where $\varphi$ is a formula that doesn't use $``b"$, and $\varphi^b$ is obtained from $\varphi$ by merely bounding all of its quantifiers by $\in b$, and $``Trans"$ signify *`is transitive'*

If we add this schema to Zermelo + foundation schema, then would the resulting theory prove replacement? That is, would it prove:

$\forall x \in a \, \exists!  y \ \varphi(x,y), \implies \\\exists b \,  \forall y \, (\exists x \in a (\varphi(x,y)) \implies y \in b) $

if it cannot prove it, then is the resulting theory equi-consistent with ZF?

Comment: Are we using a strong enough form of foundation to prove the existence of transitive closures?

Comment: @MarkSaving, Yes!

Comment: @MarkSaving, this theory does prove existence of transitive closures even without foundation! From transitive replacement every set $a$ would be an element (therefore a subset) of some transitive set, and since we have separation, then this is enough to prove existence of a transitive closure for every set.  So, that said, even the single usual axiom of foundation is enough for its purposes.